# Arithemtic between equivalent typedefs

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, typedef

I am writing a C++ compiler for my compiler class and I was wondering this.
Arithmetic between equivalent typedefs So, b/c typedefs have loose name equivalence:

```
typedef int FOO;
typedef int BAR;

int test;
FOO i;
BAR j;

i = 1;
j = 2;
test = i + j; // Code clarity
```

is this supposed to work? Are typedefs really just glorified base types or do they cascade into a hierarchy?

Comment: Whether that code should work depends entirely on the semantics of the language you're implementing, which you have not told us in your question.

Comment: "I am writing a C++ compiler"... really?   Wow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that will work fine, but think about the case when you get structs.

Comment: I thought about that case. Works the same. What point did you want to make?

Comment: @MSalters Structs use strict name equivalence, which will behave differently from other types.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++, a typedef declaration defines an alias for a type name. It does not define a new type. The compiler must resolve every typedef (recursively if necessary) to a type descriptor which contains no typedef names. (If that's impossible, program is not well-formed.)

So not only does `FOO(1) + BAR(2)` work just fine, with no implicit conversions, a variable defined as `FOO` will match `int` in a template specialization.